# A question about euclidean graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have an [Euclidean graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory#:%7E:text=A%20Euclidean%20graph%20is%20a,Euclidean%20distance%20between%20those%20points.&text=A%20Levi%20graph%20of%20a,every%20incident%20point%2Dline%20pair.) $G$, but i should changes the weight of some edge of $G$ to $+\infty$. My problem is, after this change, $G$ remain Euclidean graph or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked has the following definition:

> A Euclidean graph is a graph in which the vertices represent points in the plane, and the edges are assigned lengths equal to the Euclidean distance between those points

Since the distance between any pair of points in the plane is always finite, it follows that no euclidean graph can have infinite edge weights.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about your answer. Maybe you have another idea than setting the weight of some edges to $\infty$.

Comment: I have a Euclidean graph, i want partition this graph into two clusters such that  for some of given pair $(p_i,q_i)$ of vertices, my algorithm must don't put pair $(p_i,q_i)$ into one cluster. I set the distance between pair $(p_i,q_i)$ to $\infty$ that guarantee each point of pair will be in different cluster. But this approach doesn't work because, the result graph isn't Euclidean graph, consequntly, my algorithm doesn't work for general graph.

Comment: Are there another idea such that guarantee  that, the points given pair will be in different clusters?

Comment: Note: OP, you have four posts, apparently about this question:
[(i)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/partition-a-graph-into-two-clusters),
[(ii)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245835/how-we-can-change-the-metric-weighted-graph-such-that-it-remain-metric),
[(iii)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/143766/a-question-about-euclidean-graph),
and [(iv)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/50469/adding-a-constraint-to-input-graph).  These posts are all somewhat unclear, and cross-posting is discouraged.  I suggest you delete three of the four posts.